# A batch file that opens up IE and delays opening up a new window with my specified local file

Tags: batch-file

Ok I have a html file stored in a file with a .bat file which the bat file runs the html file. the reason being is because if I can gt the bat file to open up IE first and then my html file it will elminate the cookies problem I am having.

I have this so far...

```
@echo off
start " " "login.html"
start /wait "" "login.html" 3
start " " "login.html"
exit
```

All this is doing is opening up 3 tabs but not 1 window and delays to open my file in a new tab in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M$ IE doesn't have such a [cli option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), If you need this, you should switch to Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have got alot closer - my only query now is instead of this opening tabs I want it to open a new windows for login.html

```
@echo off
start "webpage name" "http://google.com"
choice /d y /t 1 > nul
start "webpage name" "login.html"
```